# Coffeescript click not responding(Rails 4)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to coffeescript and I made a little test script to see if it works. I've made a `link_to` button in my Rails app with class `testbutton`. The below code doesn't work however:

```
$('.testbutton').click ->
    console.log(1)
    return false
```

The output in my code is

```
  $('.testbutton').click(function() {
    console.log(1);
    return false;
  });
```

And the HTML button:

```
<a class="testbutton" href="/clients/bygroup/6">Name</a>
```

Which seems fine to me.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you verify that you have this in dom ready, i.e. `$ ->` for coffeescript.

Comment: @vinodadhikary that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Careful with `$ ->` if you're using Turbolinks though.

Comment: Why's that? 4 more to go, ugh

Comment: @muistooshort, true.  CaptainCarl please refer to this railscast which has good explanation as to why: http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?view=asciicast

Comment: A couple searches around here for `[ruby-on-rails-4] [turbolinks]` should also be helpful.